# R t-test, 1 response, multiple independent variables

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to perform a t-test between groups 'A' and 'B'. The difficulty is that although there is only one response variable, there are many observations, and the grouping (A or B) differs with each observation. My code for generating the input data is shown below.

I'd like to know how to approach doing the test, ideally so that the t-test results for each observation are presented in a table. I have a feeling 'apply' is needed but to be honest I'm not sure where to start as other searches have been futile.

```
# Matrix for response variable
N_samples <- 20
resp_vars <- matrix(runif(n=N_samples, min=0, max=1))
sample_names <- paste0("sample_", 1:N_samples )
rownames(x=resp_vars) <- sample_names
colnames(x=resp_vars) <- "resp"
resp_vars [1:5,]

# Matrix for independent variables

N_observations <- 100
ind_vars <- matrix(NA, N_observations, N_samples)
ind_vars <- apply(ind_vars, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c("A", "B"),1))
ind_var_names <- paste0("obs_", 1:N_observations)
rownames(x=ind_vars) <- ind_var_names
colnames(x=ind_vars) <- sample_names
ind_vars[1:3,1:5]
```

Comment: You need a grouping variable that has an observation for each entry. At the moment you have 2000 grouping variables and only 20  values. What are we supposed to do with that?

Answer (score 2):

I obtained an answer to my question from R-help.

The data are:

```
resp_vars <- runif(20)
names(resp_vars) <- paste0("sample_", seq(20))
ind_vars <- matrix(sample(c("A", "B"), 2000, TRUE), ncol=20, dimnames=list(paste0("obs_", seq(100)), names(resp_vars)))
```

The solution is:

```
install.packages("broom")
library("broom")
t_fit <- apply(ind_vars, 1, function(obs) t.test(resp_vars ~ obs))
t_est <- do.call(rbind, lapply(t_fit, tidy))
names(t_est) <- c("diff", "meanA", "meanB", "t", "p.value", "df", "conf.low", "conf.high")
head(t_est)
```

Apologies if the question was confusing or misleading.